# Is there a golang library for creating loopback devices on Linux?

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

I have a file. Let's call it "x". I'd like to associate "x" with a loopback device in linux. From bash, I'd type:

```
losetup -f x
```

That will create something like /dev/loop0 that I can mount wherever I'd like. When it's not mounted, I can destroy the loopback file with something like:

```
losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

I'd like to be able to do the same in golang without calling losetup from the go program. Is there a library somewhere to that implements this as I looked through the losetup source, and it looks somewhat tricky, especially the create part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an losetup library :-(

If you really don't want to call losetup from your code (which is the most sensible thing to do IMHO) then I'd copy the [losetup.c](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/klibc/usr/utils/losetup.c) source code into my go project, rename the main() function and then use [cgo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) to call the renamed main function or the relevant internals directly.